# Reduce space between images

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to reduce the space of the gray box while keeping the images centered, but I dont know what property to use. I'm using flex box if that helps.

```
.layout {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
min-height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background: rgba(185, 180, 169, 0.226);
flex: calc(100% / 3);
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
 border: 5px solid white;
}
```

[image: gray box is way too big]

Comment: I think the yellow is the padding , try to set it to 0

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Looks pretty minimal to me. I honestly dont know how else to ask it.

Comment: It's not complete. You'll need the HTML as well

Comment: So just add the HTML then?

Comment: What do you mean by gray box? Because the white space between the boxes is the border you set by yourself (`border: 5px solid white;`)

Comment: I think your problem is in the flex property within the child class. Whatever are you trying to achieve with setting it to calc(100% / 3), I don't think it works like you think it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the border for your child element**

Set few codes in css

```
img {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

.child{
    border: 0;
}
```